# SQL statement trimmed and rejected as error

Tags: sql, delphi, filter, delphi-xe5, tclientdataset

Have the following SQL statement applied to a ClientDataset as the Filter property:

```
'(((DORcode > ''00'') AND (DORcode < ''10'')) AND (((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)) AND ((SiteNumber+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity))) AND (TaxStatus > ''!''))'
```

> It gives me the following error: ')' expected but nothing found, or (for an >even longer statement): Type mismatch.

Diving on the details found that the problem is caused by the longness of the statement, parts of it are working, like:

```
'(((DORcode > ''00'') AND (DORcode < ''10'')) AND (((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity))))';
```

or any other shorter part.

All field names are valid, the dataset is  not empty, filters are working fine for all involved field names if the statement is shorter.

So, the error isn't a syntax one, is clearly caused by an internal trimming of the statement exceeding a character number limit (somewhere between 111 and 196).

> My questions are: 
>   1. Did somebody notice ever this error on Delphi XE5?
>   2. Is it a patch for it?
>   3. How to solve the filtering for the initial (long) statement in any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but can you use OnFilterRecord as a workaround?

Comment: Better to say, you should use `OnFilterRecord` for such a string mess.

Comment: @AD7six Why are you asking this, what is your reason?

Comment: Because typing in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read, and there's no reason to SHOUT at us here. The reason there are Shift keys on both sides of the keyboard are to make them easy to reach, because properly cased text is easier to read and comprehend. Typing in all CAPS will not get you an answer faster, and it's rather rude to SHOUT at people you're asking for free help to solve your problem.

Comment: @Ken I use caps the emphasize something, not to shout. Simply, I was afraid that somebody will try to find the error in those directions.  If you received this as shouting, sorry then.

Comment: The appropriate way to emphasize something is to make it **bold** not all caps.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for all styling helps :). Would be realy happy if somebody will help in my **real** problem.

Comment: Looks like you already have two answers below.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment as to whether there is a fault with XE5, but I notice you have a whole load of unnecessary brackets in the filter.  I think the following would be valid, and perhaps clearer, though without knowing all your datatypes I am not 100% sure.

```
DORcode > '00' AND 
DORcode < '10' AND 
SiteNumber + ' ' + SiteStreet + SiteCity <> OwnerAddr1 + OwnerCity AND
SiteNumber + SiteStreet + SiteCity <> OwnerAddr1 + OwnerCity AND 
TaxStatus > '!'
```

Further - I would consider building the filter like this because I think it would be clearer

```
FilterString := 'DORcode > 0 AND DORcode < 10 AND ' +
                'Trim(SiteNumber) + Trim(SiteStreet) + SiteCity <> ' +
                '     OwnerAddr1 + OwnerCity AND ' +
                'TaxStatus > ''!''';
```

Is that helpful ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, I am aware, there are many redundant brackets (put them only for readability), but this shouldn't be the error cause (actually it isn't because they work on shorter filters). Tried your variant but the compiler, obviously,  gives me unknown variable error for the field names contained in the Format command. By the other hand do not understand what difference will this make since Format will generate exactly the same string as I have write and the same statement will be transferred to the SQL parser, which gives the error?

Comment: I am unaware of any problem regarding the length of a filter string, but if you say that is the issue then shorten it.  I see that I have misread field names as variables - I will edit that.  What RDBMS are you using btw?

Comment: Thank you, but still does not help me. Your last (shorter) statement works but is **not** logically equivalent to my original. Tried to insert linefeed and carriage return characters but Delphi seems to ignore them in this Filter property. Really don't know what to do.

Comment: it should not take much to get the logic right.  Is it the quotes round `00` & `10` ?  like I said - without seeing your data I am guessing what the correct form should be

Comment: Again, the syntax is good. All my data are in string form. Every part of my statement works fine separately. The problem occurs only when the statement in longer than approx.  120 characters. I am seeking help on this strange internal trimming of the Filter string. Does anybody notice it, is there an explanation, a workout?

Comment: Could provide a better example for how strange the Filter property behaviour is:

If apply a filter (135 characters) the result is correct (389.898 records). 

If I concatenate the **same** filter twice (with an AND, which obviously must give the SAME result, it still works but I get a wrong result (527.470 records). 

If I concatenate the **same** filter three times (with two ANDs),  which also must give the SAME result, it do not works, gives an error message: ')' expected but found...

Maybe now is clear what my problem is.

Comment: The filter expression is:

'(((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)) AND ((SiteNumber+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)))'

respectively (taken twice):

'(((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)) AND ((SiteNumber+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity))) AND '+
'(((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)) AND ((SiteNumber+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)))'

and taken three times: *see next comment*

Comment: '(((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)) AND ((SiteNumber+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity))) AND '+
'(((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)) AND ((SiteNumber+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity))) AND '+
'(((SiteNumber+'' ''+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)) AND ((SiteNumber+SiteStreet+SiteCity)<>(OwnerAddr1+OwnerCity)))'

Comment: @laszlo - if you refuse to simplify, then I cannot assist you. sorry

Comment: Thank you, for your good intention. I do not refuse to simplify but in my opinion is not possible. The statement is already in its minimal form. Any change will alter its logic. If should be this possible, never came here for help. Actually, I could work around the whole problem by involving an auxiliary dataset and do cascade (nested) filtering. However, I am very upset for this unexpected bug in Delphi, and also surprised that nobody noticed it till now and, it seems, nobody even care of it. Are the Embarcadero guys ever reading these pages?

Comment: if it really is a bug then you should be able to put together a simple, generic example program to reproduce it.  If you do that then you are in a position to raise it as a bug with Emba and it will get fixed.  Your question in its present form leaves out too much context to convince anyone you have found a bug.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware of the data types. In the reformatted example 1 DORcor seems to be a string, in example 2 it is coded as number. You also combine Sitenumber (which sounds like a number) with Sitestreet which sounds more like a string.

Comment: Hi Christine, thanks for you observations, however, you didn't pay attention to my problem description. I emphasized (with all caps) that the statement parts are all good and verified, work well. Actually, all my fields are string type, even if they represent numbers. **The error cause here is not the bad syntax**. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I paid attention to your problem very well. Your first error message contains "Type mismatch.". As previous mentioned the SQL-statement is mostly a widestring which should be capable much more than 200 chars.

Comment: The error message is depending on where the system is trimming the original (good!!!!) statement. Despite my express care to avoid this type of answers, you try to find syntax errors in my statement. Tried every part separately, all work fine.  
Agree with you that the filter string is a wide one and _"should be capable much more than 200 characters"_ but IT ISN'T!!! It is trimmed by the system, could not find out where and why. You could try it easily on your system too with a dummy query. Exactly this is my problem, and waiting help from somebody who could solve THIS one.

Comment: @Christine - As I read it - this is not an Sql statement but a filter on a TClientDataset